# There are six functions, read each comment and write the return statements for each of them

Tags: javascript, function

Hi everyone I am hoping I can get some help here and someone can explain this to me. I am in a coding class and I cannot figure this out for the life of me. This is the code I need to finish. I cannot seem to get this right. Can anyone help? I have tried to add the lines of code needed multiple different ways so I finally restarted everything and I am lost.

```
// Instructions
// - Given the following 6 empty functions, add the right return statement to each of 
them to complete the activity
// Please do not change any of the function names

//This is your starting array
const arr = [10, 10, 16, 12];

function returnFirst(arr) {
  // return the first item from the array
}

function returnLast(arr) {
  // return the last item of the array
}

function getArrayLength(arr) {
  // return the length of the array
}

function incrementByOne(arr) {
  // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
  // return the array
}

function addItemToArray(arr, item) {
  // add the parameter item to the end of the array arr
  // return the array
}

function addItemToFront(arr, item) {
  // add the parameter item to the front of the array arr
  // return the array
  // hint: use the array method .unshift
}

//uncomment these lines to check results in browser console
// console.log("returnFirst result:" + returnFirst(arr))
// console.log("returnLast result:" + returnLast(arr))
// console.log("getArrayLength result:" + getArrayLength(arr))
// console.log("incrementByOne result:" + incrementByOne(arr))
// console.log("addItemToArray result:" + addItemToArray(arr, 10))
// console.log("addItemToFront result:" + addItemToFront(arr, 10))

//////////////////////////////////
//don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {
    returnFirst,
    returnLast,
    getArrayLength,
    incrementByOne,
    addItemToArray,
    addItemToFront,
  };
}
```

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: please ask a question

Comment: The questions are in the comments on the code. I cannot seem to find the correct solution.

Comment: where is it done?

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework for you. Try each one and if you run into any problems then show us what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language this is but I assume it's javascript.  The question is asking you to find the syntax to read or manipulate the initial array and tag it onto the end of a return statement.  So the first answer might be something like: `return arr[0]` which should show the first (zero indexed) item in the array.  The whole function then looks like:

```
function returnFirst(arr) {
  // return the first item from the array
  return arr[0];
}
```

Comment: My apologies it is JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for the help. The first two functions are the only ones I was able to figure out. It was the last four that really gave me issues but I wasn't able to solve them.

Comment: Try googling "javascript find the length of an array", etc.